# java Android - how can I keep Image's actual size?

Tags: java, android, parameters, android-imageview

I'm totally confused of how to keep actual size of Images!

For example, I have a png named bottom_tile.png, if I place it on layout as it is - it's one size. If I make a tiled bitmap like this :

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 

  android:src="@drawable/ver_bottom_panel_tile"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:dither="true"

/>
```

and place it on my layout, it's height will be different, although it's only one tile high so they should be exact height! Why is it happening? both cases android:layout_height="wrap_content"

When I set another png file which should stick on top and stretch from left to right and set it's android:layout_height="wrap_content" , height is also distorted, so I can't place all the desing in. what's going on ?

I just need my actual size, no more no less

I've been asked for layout - it's just 2 images, 1 is a tile, 2nd is what's in code above 
bitmap is 40%+ bigger on it than a tile

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ver_bottom_panel_tile" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/ver_bottom_panel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tiled drawable scale automatically by repeating the bitmap, unless you specify a height/width in drawable file.

Comment: it doesn't repeat tile vertically, I specified it in a first message, I said that bitmap is one tile high.the height of a tile is exactly 89 pixels,but  the picture itself becomes much larger when i put it in a repeat mode.

Comment: `tileMode` only works for the `background`, not the `src`

Comment: I know that, I put it on a background to layout. the image itself is different in size, about 40% bigger.

Comment: Maybe you should post your layout, then. It would avoid all the confusion you're seeing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you be more specific about what you are looking for ?

If you need your image to attain a minimum or the original height you could use

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

this will make your image attain a minimum height or the original height

`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

will make your image stretch left to right or width wise.

Comment: I specified that i used android:layout_height="wrap_content", I wrote it in a first message.